# How to use break or contnue

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array of admission and each student has multiple entry of payment.
Like Admission=[1,2,3,4,5,6] this is admission ids,
and Payment=[[1->1,5,6,2],[2->2,3],[3->4,7,8] this is admission id->payment_ids

```
foreach($admission as $a)
{ 
  $payment=DB::table('payement')->where('admission_id',$a->admission_id)->get();

  foreach($payment as $p)
  {
    // Here i wan if payment_date <= today_date
    // 1. Add all payment
    // 2. Else Go to the next admission id
  }
}
```

Comment: `continue` goes to the next iteration, `break` stops the whole loop

Comment: If you want to just add up the payments from today or before, why wouldn't you include that condition in your initial query, so that you only get back the relevant rows?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for something like this:

```php
foreach($admission as $a)
{ 
  $payment = DB::table('payment')->where('admission_id', $a->admission_id)->get();

  $totalPayment = 0;
  foreach($payment as $p)
  {
    if (\Carbon\Carbon::parse($p->payment_date)->lessThanOrEqualTo(\Carbon\Carbon::now())) {
       $totalPayment += $p->amount;
    }
  }
}
```

Inside of the `foreach` loop on `$payment` the code above uses [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to compare the dates. It looks like you're using Laravel's Eloquent so you should have Carbon available in your application since it's a Laravel dependency. I use Carbon to compare the dates because it knows more about dates than I do.

Next, if it's true that payment_date is less than or equal to the current date then it will add it to the `$totalPayment` for that admission. Otherwise, it will move onto the next payment. This presumably makes using `continue` or `break` unnecessary unless I am misunderstanding something.

I'm not sure what you want to do with `$totalPayment`. Right now it will be calculated for each admission and then lost.

If you want to find the total payment across all admissions you should move `$totalPayment = 0` to the line above `foreach($admission as $a)`.

If you want to find the total payment for each admission you could set a totalPayment on each admission `$a->total_payment = $totalPayment`. I would then change `$totalPayment = 0` to `$a->total_payment = 0` and change `$totalPayment += $p->amount` to `$a->totalPayment += $p->amount`.